# What is the name of this painting genre?

Tags: drawing, painting

I know the genre is related to photo realism/hyper realism, It's photo realism/hyper realism, But I want to know what's the name of it with this tools!?

They use graphite, They use brush and dark colors in it, They use different kind of black powders as color

Here is an example:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me, this seems like it is charcoal pencil art.  Google that term and check out the Images it brings up.  They are very similar.

The way this is created is the artist uses a charcoal pencil to draw on the paper, then smudges the charcoal into the picture they want to make.  The powder is actually the charcoal.  In this case, the light color comes from the paper the eye/face is drawn on.

Comment: FYI, we generally try to discourage people from answering clearly off-topic questions as it just encourages people to ask them - see the [help] for more info.

Comment: @walrus Sorry, is it off-topic ? I saw other questions like that, so I asked it, Even I read some meta questions about a question like this and I thought it should be Okay

Comment: @computercarguy They use graphite, I'll update the question

Comment: @DarkSuniuM actually on re-reading it (and the [meta discussion](https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212/what-guidelines-should-we-set-for-identification-style-questions), this question is on topic; my apologies.